# Hover state for menu is not working - something to do with z-index?

Tags: html, css, z-index

The ":hover" CSS state on the navigation bar my website [Pixel Crescent](http://pixelcrescent.com) is not working right now. I have spent the past little while tinkering with my CSS and HTML trying to find and fix the root of the problem, but have had no luck.

I'm suspecting z-index to be at fault, and it's quite possible and I have been having quite a few problems with the z-index and have been using it a bit.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a syntax error in your code: `.navbar ul li a: hover`
Remove the space after the `:` and it will work.